# netty why channel is not yet connected

Tags: netty

a client channel is initialized in a server inbound channel `channelActive` method. And I could see pcap has a 3-way handshake completed (253 is the local host, 15 is the remote one)

[image: packets in pcap]

But when writing to the client channel, it throws

> java.nio.channels.NotYetConnectedException: null  at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0()(Unknown
>   Source)

to my understandings, client channel should be in active state, because a 3-way handshake means the client channel is ready to send packets. But by evaluating clientChannel.isActive(), result is false, weird.

server inbound channel:

```
Channel clientChannel;
@Override
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    final Channel inboundChannel = ctx.channel();

    try {
        Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
        b.group(inboundChannel.eventLoop())
            .channel(inboundChannel.getClass())
            .handler(new SomeClientChannelInitializer(ctx));

        // Make the connection attempt.
        ChannelFuture f = b.connect(host, port);
        clientChannel = f.channel();
    } catch (Exception e) {// no exception}
}

@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
    log.info("receive: {}", msg);
    clientChannel.writeAndFlush(msg -> this::pojo);
}
```

**EDIT:**
I solved this by adding `wait`

```
  f = b.connect(host, port);
  clientChannel = f.channel();
  try {
      f.await(3L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      boolean success = clientChannelFuture.isSuccess();
```

I am not sure if this is appropriate, official proxy example does not have this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either need to write via a `ChanneFutureListener` that you attach to the connect `ChannelFuture` or you need to `sync()` / `wait()` on it.

Remember everything in netty is asynchronous which means when the `connect` method returns and you trigger the `write` the `Channel` may not be fully connected yet.